# How to know when Android is ready inside Genymotion VM?

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm launching a Genymotion VM using:

```
$ /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name <VM_ID> &
$ sleep 30
```

Is there a way to know when Android's ready to install & launch an app instead of just waiting 30s?

`adb devices` lists the VM in the very early boot process, so I can't rely on it.

Comment: You could try `adb shell ps` in a try/wait loop until you see the presence of whatever the usual launcher activity is, or you could watch logcat for promising system messages or even create a package with a boot receiver that would generate a custom message and watch for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **`adb`** works, you can simply check for one of the following properties:

- `sys.boot_completed`
- `init.svc.bootanim`
- `dev.bootcomplete`

Sample code to poll on the target:

```
adb shell 'while [ ""`getprop dev.bootcomplete` != "1" ] ; do sleep 1; done'
```

Sample code to poll target from the host:

```
while [ `adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed` -nq "1" ] ; do sleep 1; done
```

---

Alternately, you could simple parse the output of `adb logcat` for a specific log/keyword that occurs at the point of time you want to track.

Comment: This works most of the time, but `sys.boot_completed` has a tendency to fire up too early. I used `init.svc.bootanim` instead, and also made sure that `adb shell` exited with code `0` in case it couldn't reach the device during the early startup stage. Thank you so much!

Comment: This works well, provided the emulator is already started (but not ready). I first run an 'abd devices' loop and when the device is listed, do this.

Comment: none of those three properties get reported to me - using arm emulator.

Comment: This might be a limitation of the emulator. Also Android itself might have changed in this aspect over the last 6years. Unfortunately, i do not know more to update this answer further as i have moved on to other things.